# Lead recordtypes (BusinessProcess) in unlocked packages Winter'20

Tags: salesforcedx, unlocked-package, winter20

ApiV47 (Winter'20) does not support BusinessProcess metadata anymore. In order to have RecordTypes on Lead you need to have BusinessProcess. So we do have a few. 
So far we deployed the code using SFDX unlocked packages. However this doesn't work any more as we get "Unsupported metadata type: [BusinessProcess]" error.
If the BusinessProcess is removed from the repo then the Lead recordtypes have missing dependencies. 
If the Lead recordtypes are removed too then the Apex Classes have missing dependencies. So this isn't a viable solution.

Any known workaround/solution?

(Yes, the classes can be rewritten as to have the SOQL queries in strings with "RecordTypeId" clauses added dynamically so the code can be deployed to empty scratch orgs without test failures. However this is more like dailywtf's turf. I'd avoid this at all costs.)

Any comments are welcome.

Comment: We are also hit hard by this.  I don't remember where this was documented in release notes.  Did you create a ticket to SF asking about reasons for this?

Comment: @akarnid: Yes, we created a ticket to SF. So far we only got a pointer to https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/47
which shows this is a feature, not a bug... Still waiting for a real explanation/workaround from them. In the meantime I thought maybe someone has a solution already here.

Comment: Yeah we are getting that WorkflowRule, PathAssistant and BusinessProcess are also not supported any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known issue that will be corrected.  See https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?Id=a1p3A000001Sa3n

Comment: Great news, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you can try to build your package with the flag --apiversion and use previous api version

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_package.htm

Comment: we have tried that and it is also not working, we have tried various combinations and still getting errors when trying to create package version...

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for us either. We have already tried this, just forgot to mention in the original post.